# How to implement wait in a method for another method to be get over in java?

Tags: java

I have a set of methods say `m1`,`m2`,`m3`,`m4`. Each one need to wait for previous method to finish. If I call `m3`, it must wait for `m2`. I thought of using flag for each method, if finished mark it. but for notifying, if `m1` says `notify()`, I want this notify only for `m2`, not for other waiting methods.

I have a component `A`, which has `m1`,`m2`,`m3` as input methods and `m4` as output method. Once `m3` happens it will call `m4` to produce output. But `m1`,`m2`,`m3` has to be executed in sequence and can be called from different classes. Waiting and corresponding signal must be there.

How can I go about implementing this?

Comment: You just want m1, m2, m3 and m4 to execute in order, each waiting for the previous one? Just do:

    m1();
    m2();
    m3();
    m4();

I'm guessing you want something slightly different to happen, though. Can you explain how what I wrote above doesn't do what you want?

Comment: I don't know why, but this recall me Observer pattern...

Comment: I do not see the point, if they wait for each other, just execute one after one.

Comment: methods are not called from one class, they can be called from different classes, at random time.

Comment: so why not having 4 methods, where m4() executes m3() first; where m3() executes m2() first; where m2() executes m1() first...

Comment: I'm guessing that each method is called from a different thread, but you haven't actually said that anywhere in your question...

Comment: just updated the question. hope it gives better idea now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want locks, but barriers: m(n + 1) has to wait until m(n) has been called. Below code assume there is only one sequence or method calls (and that m1/2/3 are called from different threads or in proper sequence on the same thread or you'll wait forever on a latch). If it can happen multiple times, it needs to be reset (or maybe you can get fancy with a Phaser).

```
private CountDownLatch m2latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
private CountDownLatch m3latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

public void m1() {
  // handle input
  m2latch.countDown();
}

public void m2() {
  m2latch.await();
  // handle input (m1 has been called)
  m3latch.countDown();
}

public void m3() {
  m3latch.await();
  // do output (both m1 + m2 have been called)
}
```

However, this is bit weird design, since you want to do it in sequence you should just do all the work in the output method, which waits until all input is in.

```
 private CountDownLatch inputLatch = new CountDownLatch(3);
 private Object[] input = new Object[3];

 public void setInput(int i, Object data) {
   input[i] = data;
   inputLatch.countDown(); // perhaps better check all input set
 }

 public Object processInput() {
   inputLatch.await();
   return process(input); // process in sequence
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

BlockingQueues could help, but not if you're using a ThreadPoolExecutor.  ThreadPoolExecutor doesn't come with an out of the box solution to block when the queue is full (this is part of the executor, not a function of the queue, since the executor uses BlockingQueue.offer which never blocks, and if the queue is full uses the RejectedExecutionHandler).  You could implement your own RejectedExecutionHandler which blocks until it can put stuff in the queue, but here's a quick deterministic way with locks:

```
ReentrantLock l1 = new ReentrantLock();
ReentrantLock l2 = new ReentrantLock();
ReentrantLock l3 = new ReentrantLock();

l1.lock();
l2.lock();
l3.lock();


// pass l1,l2,l3 along to the threads running these methods, so they are available to the methods:

public void m1() {
 try {
  // do stuff
 }
 finally {
   l1.unlock();
 }
}

public void m2() {
 l1.lock();
 try {
  // do stuff
 }
 finally {
   l2.unlock();
 }
}

public void m3() {
 l2.lock();
 try {
  // do stuff
 }
 finally {
   l3.unlock();
 }
}

public void m4() {
 l3.lock();
 // do stuff
}
```

Comment: ps:  if you want an arbitrary number of methods, you could always use an array of ReentrantLock, and pass two locks to each method.  One to lock on start, and one to unlock on finish (accounting for the fact that they could be null and doing nothing).

Answer (score 0):

I would set up a counter as an int and each method has to wait until the counter hits their number before they can go. That way, each method just has to increment the counter and you can insert more later.

Comment: Isn't that basically a `Semaphore`?

Comment: yes, wait part is fine, but how to signal the waiting method to execute once its previous method is done. dont want to do periodic check.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution is to just use four different lock objects. (Or indeed run them in the same thread, but that's probably not what you want.)

With a bit more detail there might be a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that one, depends if I understood the problem correctly:

```
public void m4() {
    m3();
    do something;
}

public void m3() {
    m2();
    do something;
}

public void m2() {
   m1();
   do something;
}

public void m1() {
   do something;
}
```